# I'm getting an error when I try to login to the back end of an expressionengine 1 site. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: login, core

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home2/sitename/public_html/system/EE/core/core.session.php on line 1049
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/sitename/public_html/system/EE/core/core.session.php:1049) in /home2/sitename/public_html/system/EE/core/core.functions.php on line 752
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/sitename/public_html/system/EE/core/core.session.php:1049) in /home2/sitename/public_html/system/EE/core/core.functions.php on line 325

The line being referenced in the error is:

> if ($query->row['count'] >= 4)

Comment: since you say it's an EE1 site, you might try to downgrade the php version. See if it goes away on php 5.3

Comment: It is currently running on 5.3.

Comment: Must have been a missing file or a permissions issue. To resolve I zipped up the files from the original server using file manager in cPanel (retains permissions). I then uploaded the files to new server and unzipped using file manager. From there I configured normally.